# Firebase, Changing User password via Email with unique password requirements

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, Firebase offers the option to send an email to a users email who wishes to change their password. Unfortunately, Firebase does not allow you to edit their password requirements which I believe is locked at requiring only 6 characters.

For many people this is inadequate and insecure.

I recently made an application that allows users to create quizzes either for themselves or for others. In this application, I stores personal information of my users and I wanted to make sure that their accounts were secure so I required more from my passwords. Unfortunately, when a user wishes to change their email, the default Firebase function does not keep my security which leads to confusion as a user can change their passwords according to Firebase's lax constraints but then they still couldn't log in because they used an invalid password. (I blocked invalid passwords from the text box before even checking with Firebase).

After I encountered this error, I came to StackOverflow for help to see if anyone else had this issue and came up with a solution. Unfortunately, I was met with harsh criticism and harassment by users who claim to be Firebase officials and Administrators who did not care about my question.

Then, I after a week of research and testing, I found the solution using React and 3rd party libraries to handle this.

Please, see my answer below and if you have a more creative solution, I would be interested in seeing that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, the only answer is to create your own mailer service with your own basic mailer service, host website, and API.

What you need:
An application which uses Firebase.
A hosted API which uses Firebase and a 3rd party Mailer such as Node with NodeMailer - hosted on Heroku
A React app which can communicate with the API

What I did:

First, I created my API which accepts calls from my specified IP addresses. This API can receive requests to reset a password when the password is known or unknown. When the password is known, I send an email to the user using NodeMailer and I send a special HTML file so the email looks official. It is quite easy to copy the layout of Firebase's emails if you wish.
More Info can be found here: https://nodemailer.com/message/

Then, I created a React App that is hosted on Heroku. When the user clicks a link in the email, it will send them to this website with the required information in the query. This app, much like when the Firebase link is clicked is just a simple text box and submit button. However, now you can customize it to require password confirmation with a second text box. You can also add a company logo and custom colors so it isn't so HTML 1 looking like the link you see from Firebase. Most importantly, you can now control the password that the user enters to add your unique requirements.

On submit, the app will send the new password, username and old password if available to the API.

If you do not know how to create a React App or a Node API, you can see a detailed tutorial here: https://www.techandstartup.com/tutorials/build-api-with-node-express-and-mongodb

Finally, the API can log into the users account if a password is present and then change the password. Detailed steps can be seen from: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/firebase+user+change+password
If a current password is not present, then the API can delete the user and recreate it with the desired password. Deleting a user can be seen: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/firebase+delete+user Then you simply recreate a user. Example code: https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?q=firebase%20createUserWithEmailAndPassword

With these steps, you can now send a password reset email to a user. The email will be completely unique as you will be designing it yourself. The password will be to your exact specifications as your React App will control the data on submit. And the page itself will look much more user friendly as it's not the default Firebase page.

Hopefully this helps you or your company with working around the Firebase reset password with email function. I am still holding out hope that another user may have a more elegant or basic solution than this as creating an API and hosting a website just for 1 function is not appealing in many cases.